# Why is permission being denied after asking user?

Tags: android, permissions

I have the permissions in my manisfest for api 22-:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

And the runtime check for permissions as well for api 23+:

```
private void requestGpsPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, 1);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
}
```

And I still got the errors:

```
 Writing exception to parcel
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=20520, uid=10089 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)

Failed to clear out contacts
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{9b0bd73 20520:com.google.android.apps.plus/u0a89} (pid=20520, uid=10089) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3594)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4799)
                                                                       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1466)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                       at ddt.a(PG:447)
                                                                       at ddt.b(PG:1396)
                                                                       at ddu.run(PG:333)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am trying to run the app in a Android 6.0 device. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Your permission-requesting code is rather strange, as you are attempting to queue up three separate dialogs. Beyond that, are you sure that you are waiting to run this thread (where your crash occurs) until after you have received permission? Remember that `requestPermissions()` is asynchronous -- when that method returns, the user has not even been *asked* about the permission, let alone have granted it.

Comment: The queued dialogs are not a problem, they appear one right after the other, and i call them as soon as i start an activity that has no action while the dialogs are being displayed. The actions are determined by button click. And even if it did cause a problem, the dialogs are displayed just once, when I restart the app the permissions are already there and I got the same error over and over :-(

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for 2 days I finally made it work. I was missing the following method:

```
1 @Override
2 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
3     // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
4     if (grantResults.length > 0
5             && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
6         // permission granteed
7        P.toast(this, "permission granteed :-)");
8         getHeaders();
9     } else {
10        // permission denied
11        P.toast(this, "permission denied :-(");
12    }
13    return;
14}
```

I had to modify the verification method as well, so in case I already have the permissions It call getHeaders() from there:

```
1 private void requestGpsPermission() {
2     if (
3             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
4                     Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
5                     != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
6                     ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
7                             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
8                             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
9                     ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
10                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
11                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
12            ) {
13        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
14                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
15                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
16                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
17        }, 1);
18    } else {
19        getHeaders();
20    }
21}
```

Note that I call the same method on line 8 of the first mehotd and line 19 of the second.